# Mutiple Entities in single LUIS Intent

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I was digging around, but I wasn't able to find what I was looking for. I am playing with LUIS and I try to define an intent like:

Can you list all the [cities] in [USA], [Canada], [Germany] .....

Where [cities] is a value of one entity and all the countries are part of second entity.

So the first question is can I get all the entities pre-mapped on my back-end instead of looping through all the result.Entites and checking what type of entities they are?

The second questsion is can LUIS detect the multiple country entities? I mean can I setup the intent somehow so I can enter an intent with one country and ten countries all to be detected?

Thanks for your time and suggestions. It's appreciated

Comment: You'll want to set up the countries as [list entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/add-entities#list-entities)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the goal is for the 1st question, do you care about the cities being mapped specifically? As in, are you differentiating between cities like Los Angeles and Barcelona, or do you not care about this and only want to know which entities are countries and which entities are cities? When you build a list entity, you can extract the entity afterwards and store that on your backend. For the 2nd question, LUIS can detect multiple country entities. If you use a list entity, LUIS uses RegExp to detect matches.